# Cleaning Georgian floorboards

Tags: repair, wood

How would you recommend cleaning Georgian floorboards to get them back to a close to original state? I was thinking of using a paint scraper for the paint and then can you recommend a polish? I think sanding might not be a good idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sanding is a great way to restore this floor to original condition. Just scraping the paint off will leave gouges that will have to be smoothed out, then those areas will be lighter than the rest of the floor. It will be more work to sand but rental sanders are available at most home stores. Afterwards, any polish/oil like Mixwax would do the job.

Comment: Don't forget to punch all the nail heads down before you start sanding ;)

Comment: You could rent a floor sander that would make the job much easier.

Comment: @Smith: "It will be more work to sand but _rental sanders are available_ at most home stores." That was noted already. I'd add that they're available at tool rental places, too. The kind that rent snakes and scaffold and backhoes will have floor sanders as well.